# Is it possible to make equipment of items(weapon/armor) through Hasmap(key is part of body and value is armor or weapon if it is hand)

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, polymorphism

I have a task to make a project in java with the usage of ArrayList, hashmap, abstract classes, and interface. I decided to develop a text-based RPG in java. I want to use abstract classes for monsters, ArrayList for inventory and hashmap for equipping armors and weapons, however, I don't really figure out if it is possible to make equip function with hashmap.
I was thinking to make something like this

```
public HashMap<PartOfBody , Weapon/Armor> equipment;
```

I would love to hear from you about any ideas about how to do it.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. Hint: `Weapon` and `Armor` could both be kind of `Item`. But for now your question is very broad

Comment: Any class which has correctly overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods could be a key in the HashMap. Both methods should take into account all significant fields of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement something along the lines of this:

```
public Abstract class Equipment {}

public class Weapon extends Equipment {}

public class Armor extends Equipment {}

public class BodyPart {
    String part;
    public BodyPart(String part) {
        this.part = part;
    }
}

public class RPG {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      HashMap<BodyPart, Equipment> equipment = new HashMap<BodyPart, Equipment>();
      equipment.put(new BodyPart("Arm"), new Weapon());
      equipment.put(new BodyPart("Head"), new Armor());
      equipment.put(new BodyPart("Arm"), new Armor());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only ways I see you can do this is either, have a `HashMap<PartOfBody , Object> equipment` 
or create an interface/abstract class `BodyItem` which both `Weapon` and `Armor` implement/extend, then have a Weapon `HashMap equipment.